# How to know if an activity is opened from a link in android and fetch the GET parameter from the link?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have both website and android application for the website.when user clicks on a link of my website it opens that up in my android application. But the problem is there is an important information present in the link which i need to fetch and the activity will make a server request upon that. To be precised the link looks like this: www.example.com/post.php?id=123 I need to get the ID part of the link when the activity is opened so that I can show information about posts bearing the ID. I have added the opening of the link in my app with help of intent filter but I am stuck at getting the GET parameter of the link.How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your activity is opened via the link, you can retrieve that URL from the `intent` like so:

```
String url = getIntent().getData().toString();
```

Then you can use `.substring` to get the parameters:

```
String id = url.substring(url.indexOf("id=") + 3)
```

OR, you can use Airbnb's library to achieve the result in a more elegant way, you can learn about it on [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch).

Comment: No need for substring, just use getQueryParameter from the Uri: String id = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("id");

Answer (score 1):

```
myLink = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
```

If the string/url was `www.example.com/post.php?id=123` the string will now return `123`.